# Why are my enemies disappearing on startup in the godot engine

Tags: godot

I am relatively new to the godot engine and am having a problem about the enemies disappearing on version 3.3.2. In the editor, the enemy nodes are positioned correctly. However, when I click on the play button, they disappear from the game. This is my enemy script:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var motion = Vector2()

var Health = 100

var bullet = preload("res://Art/Bullet.png")
var explosion = load("res://Particles.tscn").instance()
var bulletSpeed = 1000

func _process(delta):


  if Health <= 0:
     queue_free()
     print(position)

func _physics_process(delta):
    var world = get_parent()
    var Player = world.get_node("Player")


    position += (Player.position - position)/40
    
    move_and_collide(motion)



func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):

    
    Health -= 20

   body.queue_free()
   queue_free()
```

And this is my entire project: https://github.com/Ripple-Studios/Godot-Wild-Jam-36-Game-Ripple-Studios . What is the problem in this scenario?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the code in your question:

- If something is up with the motion, it could make the enemy move to unexpected positions:

  - The variable `motion` will always be `Vector2.ZERO` unless you are setting it from some other code.
  - It appears all your motion is driven by writing to `position`.
- You have calls to `queue_free` which could be removing the enemy.

*Also, you have unused variables.*

---

After running your linked code:

- All the enemy motion is driven by `position` (know collision will not prevent its movement), your `motion` and `move_and_slide` are doing nothing.
- The player a child `Area2D` which has an invalid signal connection. That `Area2D` is also colliding with its parent (the player, in this case). Which results in an error because it can't find the method to call.
- The enemy has a child `Area2D` that will trigger the `"body_entered"` signal because it is colliding with its parent (the enemy itself). Which results in a call to `_on_Area2D_body_entered`, which results in calling `queue_free`, which removes the enemy. **This is the problem you are asking about.**

---

For solutions, you can:

- In `_on_Area2D_body_entered` check what it collided with, and it if it is itself, do nothing. *It is also a common practice to take advantage of node groups with [`is_in_group`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-is-in-group). See also [Groups](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html#groups).*
- Use collision layers and masks to make the `Area2D` not collide with its parent. *Note that layers and mask may not work as you expect. There is a proposal to change it: [Make physics layers and masks logic simple and consistent](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/2775).*